# Difference between pod 'FirebaseAnalytics' and pod 'Firebase/Analytics' in CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I recently came across two different ways of specifying Firebase Analytics(or other Firebase products) in a CocoaPods Podfile:

```
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

I found information suggesting that the second one is a subspec, while the first is a standalone pod. However, I'm not entirely clear on how CocoaPods works. Can someone explain if there is a difference between these two syntaxes, and if so, what is it?

Additionally, I noticed that when using them, they seem to pull different dependencies. Could someone elaborate on the differences in dependencies that these two syntaxes might introduce?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`'Firebase/Analytics'` is an alias, it doesn't contain any own sources and actually depends on `FirebaseAnalytics`.

If you look at their respective Podspecs ([1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.19.0/Firebase.podspec.json), [2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/10.20.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json)) you'll notice that `Firebase/Analytics` depends on `Firebase/Core`, which in return depends on `FirebaseAnalytics`.

But there's a trick - both pods are updated separately. For example, if you install `Firebase/Analytics` at the time of writing (01/16/24) you'll have version `10.19.0` installed, but if you use `FirebaseAnalytics` instead you'll have `10.20.0`. And my guess is `FirebaseAnalytics` is updated faster in general, since `Firebase/Analytics` is a subspec and only gets updates once all of its subspecs' dependencies get their updates.

Comment: which one is right to use if I need only analytics in my project?